# how do we reset the size of safari devtools with applescript for ios simulators?

Tags: safari, applescript, ios-simulator, devtools

how do we reset the size of safari dev-tools with apple-script for simulators? The url can be random and anything(any site). As can be seen from the screenshot, there is a setting option we get in safari devtools for simulators, where we can set the devtools size with "zoom" option. I wanted it to set to 100% with applescript doing the same job.

This script i was trying as shown below is trying to activate safari, then go the simulator device and click on the url. Then i am stuck on how to click on the settings tab on safari devtools and finally on zoom option to resize devtools with applescript

Below is the image:

[Please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACKYU.jpg)

```
tell application "System Events"
tell application process "Safari"
    if not (exists menu bar item "Develop" of menu bar 1) then return
    tell menu 1 of menu bar item "Develop" of menu bar 1
        set simulatorMenuName to the name of (menu items whose name starts with "Simulator") as string
        if simulatorMenuName is equal to "" then return
        set simulatorMenuNameMenuItems to the name of menu items of menu 1 of menu item simulatorMenuName
        if item 1 of simulatorMenuNameMenuItems is not "Safari" then return
        repeat with i from 1 to count simulatorMenuNameMenuItems
            if item i of simulatorMenuNameMenuItems is equal to missing value then
                set menuItemNumber to i - 1
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
        tell menu 1 of menu item simulatorMenuName to click menu item menuItemNumber
    end tell
end tell
```

end tell

Comment: What have **you** tried? Stack Overflow **is not** a code writing service!  Is the **URL** in the screen shot something anyone can go to without a login? If yes then please provide the **URL** in written form so we do not have to manually type it. Have a look at: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @user3439894 I am still exploring on this and don't have much idea. Url is something we provide where login is not required.

Comment: RE: "Url is something we provide where login is not required." --  Then please provide the **URL** in written form so we do not have to manually type it.

Comment: @user3439894 Url can be random and anything(any site). I am facing a problem where sometimes devtools size is increased from normal when loading any url and sometimes it is fine. So, i was thinking of an applescript which always resizes the devtools size to normal when the session closes.

Comment: @user3439894  give me a moment, let me confirm if the url is same always.

Comment: @user3439894 this is happening with random urls. As you can see in the image, there is a zoom option we get in the devtools settings icon, i was looking for something which always sets it to "zoom-100%".

Comment: RE: "Url can be random and anything(any site)." -- The point is that you provide a working **URL** that can be used by anyone without the need to login. RE: "I am facing a problem where sometimes devtools size is increased from normal when loading any url and sometimes it is fine. " -- Then please edit your question and provide relevant details so it's not a guessing game. Again, please take the time to read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @user3439894 sure, editing the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user3439894 have added the description now.

Comment: As you have not provide a **URL**, not requiring a login, and in written form, the only thing I have to offer is the possibility of using **JavaScript** in conjunction with **AppleScript** to check the _value_ of **Zoom:** and set it to the _value_ you want.

Comment: @user3439894 is url and loggin necessary for the devtools to set the size?

Comment: @user3439894 give me some moment, if needed will edit the question. just checking the required things you asked

Comment: RE: "is url and loggin necessary for the devtools to set the size?" --  As you have not provide a **URL**, in written form, or any information or instructions even bring up a page resembling the screen shot, so I'm not sure how you expect me to answer that. Again, please take the time to read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, What version of **macOS**  and **Safari** are you running?

Comment: @user3439894 have updated the image in the description. First i open safari using "open -a safari", then i go to develop option-> then to my simulator device and i select the url from there, if i select that url, then the devtools will open, i will click on settings and then zoom option to select zoom size to 100%. My safari version is from 14.1 to 15 and macos is bigsur that am using now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to test in the same environment as you at the present time, however, he *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** and **Safari** version 14.0.3 (15610.4.3.1.6, 15610) with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Safari" to activate
delay 0.2
tell application "System Events"
    tell front window of application process "Safari"
        
        if (value of pop up button 1 of group 19 of ¬
            group 4 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of ¬
            group 1 of group 1) is not "100%" then
            
            click ¬
                pop up button 1 of group 19 of ¬
                group 4 of UI element 1 of ¬
                scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1
            
            delay 0.1
            
            click ¬
                menu item "100%" of menu 1 of group 1
            
        end if
        
    end tell
end tell
```

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* assumes that the *front window* of **Safari** is already loaded to the target *page* and or **Web Inspector** *tab/window*.

The target *tab* of the **Web Inspector** does not appear to be **JavaScript** scriptable via **AppleScript**, however, it can be scripted using **UI Scripting**. Note that **UI Scripting** is *kludgy* at best and prone to failure due to changes in the *hierarchical **UI element** structure* of the **OS** and or *application* being scripted. Changes to the *example* **AppleScript** *code* presented may need to be made to your use in **macOS Big Sur**, or any other version of **macOS** and or **Safari** other than what it was tested and worked under.

You can use **Accessibility Inspector** to check the *hierarchical **UI element** structure* under the current version of **macOS** and **Safari** your are using. You can also use **AppleScript** to query the various *hierarchical **UI element** structures* to ascertain which it the right one for the `pop up button` *button*.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: can we do something like i have shared in the description? am not able to figure out how to go to the zoom option for simulator and set to 100 percent.

Comment: getting this error for the code you gave while running on script editor with simulator open - System Events got an error: Can’t get window 1 of application process "Safari". Invalid index.

Comment: @Ritesh Kumar, I'd suggest you reread my answer in its entirety. It works as stated under the conditions expressed and provides some guidance on how to adapt it to a different version of **macOS** and **Safari**, as I am not able to test under the same environment as you at the present time. You are just going to have to do the research and learn how to adapt the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ for your own usage or wait until someone else provides other _code_.

Comment: @Ritesh Kumar, Testing under **macOS Big Sur** 11.6 and **Safari** version 14.1.2 (16611.3.10.1.6) the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ presented in my answer also works for it too, Just as stated for **macOS Catalina**. Note however, when the **General** _tab_ of the **Web Inspector** _window_ is opened there is nothing else showing like in the original screen shot you first linked to your question. So again, the last paragraph under the **Notes:** _section_ still applies. Here is a screen shot of the _window_ the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ works on: https://i.imgur.com/vS9MtYB.png

Comment: can you check this screenshot - https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/5569/7Hqt8y.png
I have opened simulator and script editor and using the same code you sent.

Comment: this is another screenshot of the error i am getting, any idea why it is not working on my bigsur? my bisgur is 11.3.1 : https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/2586/0ha6jQ.png

Comment: can't we do something like this - https://cl1p.net/example and try to click the zoom option?

Comment: @Ritesh Kumar, Again, I'd suggest you reread my answer in its entirety! No offense intended, but do you understand **English**? I'm asking because you certainly do not seem to be getting what I've said, even with the screen shot I've linked in my previous comment. -- I have to be honest and blunt, based on everything that has transpired in this question and some of the other interactions and questions you've asked on **Ask Different**, I will henceforth not respond to or reply to anything you post! I'm done.

Comment: sorry for the incovenience caused. Will check and mark this answer. Thanks alot.

Comment: just a question, will the UI elements will always be different for different safari versions? my safari version is 14.1 (16611.1.21.161.6)

Comment: @user3439894-this is working when i have opened the web inspector settings tab. i was looking for a script which will go to the settings tab in safari devtools with the script itself and then change the size of devtools with zoom option. Is this even possible? can all the process be automated with applescript?

Comment: Have added the description for the question, also i did posted on what i was trying to do. I am opening safari devtools after clicking on the simulator device then the url. I don't have any idea on how to go to the settings tab and then to the zoom option once i run the applescript shown in the description? can it be a full automated process with an applescript from opening the safari devtools to clicking on the zoom option with 100 percent size?

Comment: if there is some other way, then do let me know.

Comment: I am posting another question similar to this then and marking this answer. Will post the question according to my requirement since i want a script which will do all the process right from starting the devtools to clicking on the zoom option.